# what is the shell command which can give a list of the size of current directory which is used for downloading?

Tags: linux, shell

```
watch -n 3 du -sh >> log
```

this command may update the value every 3 seconds, but only latest size of current directory is stored in file log, **the old values are simplely overwrite**, so how to reserve the old values, and store it to the file named log?

Answer (score 2):

`watch` does not overwrite the file. In fact, it is not possible to overwrite a file in the middle of a redirection.

What happens is `watch` only saves the differences between successive screens (using ANSI codes). It was not designed to be used to log something (therefore it is called "watch", anyway).

Use `xxd` to see the real content of the log file.

Comment: @hugemeow: `cat` does not display special characters as ANSI codes. That's why it seems like the file has been overwritten. You can use `cat -v` though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might do more what you want:

```
while sleep 3
do
  du -sh
done >> log &
tail -F log
```